# Different forms for different kinds of users

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I am creating a register/login system in Visual Studio using Access as a database. I want to know how to after the user login, I can connect different forms to a user. For example:

User1- Form1
User2- Form2
User3- Form3
User4- Form4

I expected to have separate forms for separate users.

Comment: Assuming a separate Form for each user is actually a practical thing to do, maybe you could name your forms with a convention that includes the user name. Then you will know at runtime the name of the Form to open. Your requirements are very brief and vague though, so nobody can really give you an answer.

Comment: Create a mapping table and show the relevant form based on a lookup.

Comment: Do they really need different forms or different sets of same data source? If you already have a login procedure, apply filter criteria to form. In either case, mapping table may be useful.

Comment: Hi, does the comment above can help you?